# I have an issue, I am working on RCNN in python I want to use UNet instead of CNN to detect plant but there is an error occurred

Tags: issue-tracking

I am getting a `ValueError` which says that `x` (images tensor) and `y` (labels) should have the same length. This is part of my code:

```
X_new= np.array(train_images)
y_new= np.array(train_labels)
T_new=np.array(test_images)
y1_new=np.array(test_labels)
print(len(X_new))
print(len(y_new))
```

The output shows me that `X_new` has a length of 128 and `y_new` has a length of 11194. Can someone please help me fix this error? Below is the rest of my code for reference.

```py
BATCH_SIZE = 64
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000

def double_conv_block(x, n_filters):
    # Conv2D then ReLU activation
    x = layers.Conv2D(n_filters, 3, padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal")(x)
    # Conv2D then ReLU activation
    x = layers.Conv2D(n_filters, 3, padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal")(x)

    return x

def downsample_block(x, n_filters):
    f = double_conv_block(x, n_filters)
    p = layers.MaxPool2D(2)(f)
    p = layers.Dropout(0.3)(p)
    return f, p

def upsample_block(x, conv_features, n_filters):
    # upsample
    x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(n_filters, 3, 2, padding="same")(x)
    # concatenate
    x = layers.concatenate([x, conv_features])
    # dropout
    x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
    # Conv2D twice with ReLU activation
    x = double_conv_block(x, n_filters)

    return x


# inputs
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(128, 128, 2))
# encoder: contracting path - downsample
# 1 - downsampl
f1, p1 = downsample_block(inputs, 64)
# 2 - downsample
f2, p2 = downsample_block(p1, 128)
# 3 - downsample
f3, p3 = downsample_block(p2, 256)
# 4 - downsample
f4, p4 = downsample_block(p3, 512)
# 5 - bottleneck
bottleneck = double_conv_block(p4, 1024)
# decoder: expanding path - upsample
# 6 - upsample
u6 = upsample_block(bottleneck, f4, 512)
# 7 - upsample
u7 = upsample_block(u6, f3, 256)
# 8 - upsample
u8 = upsample_block(u7, f2, 128)
# 9 - upsample
u9 = upsample_block(u8, f1, 64)
# outputs
outputs = layers.Conv2D(2, 1, padding="same", activation="sigmoid")(u9)
# unet model with Keras Functional API
#final layer for output
flat = Flatten()(outputs)
out = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(flat)
unet_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, out, name="U-Net")

#opt = Adam(lr=0.0001)
#model_final.compile(loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer = opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
unet_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                   loss="binary_crossentropy",
                   metrics="accuracy")

unet_model.summary()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

class MyLabelBinarizer(LabelBinarizer):
    def transform(self, y):
        Y = super().transform(y)
        if self.y_type_ == 'binary':
            return np.hstack((Y, 1 - Y))
        else:
            return Y

    def inverse_transform(self, Y, threshold=None):
        if self.y_type_ == 'binary':
            return super().inverse_transform(Y[:, 0], threshold)
        else:
            return super().inverse_transform(Y, threshold)
lenc = MyLabelBinarizer()
Y = lenc.fit_transform(y_new)
lenc1 = MyLabelBinarizer()
Y1 = lenc1.fit_transform(y1_new)
X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(X_new, y_new, test_size=0.30)

#y_train = np.asarray(y_train1).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
#y_test = np.asarray(y_test1).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
#X_train = np.asarray(X_train1).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
#X_test = np.asarray(X_test1).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
trdata = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, rotation_range=90)
traindata=trdata.flow(train_images,Y,batch_size=32)
#traindata = tf.image.flip_left_right(train_images)
tsdata = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, rotation_range=90)
#testdata = tf.image.flip_left_right(test_images)
testdata=tsdata.flow(test_images,Y1,batch_size=32)

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping

BATCH_SIZE = 64
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000
NUM_EPOCHS = 20

TRAIN_LENGTH = len(traindata)
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = TRAIN_LENGTH // BATCH_SIZE
VAL_SUBSPLITS = 5
TEST_LENTH = len(testdata)
VALIDATION_STEPS = TEST_LENTH // BATCH_SIZE // VAL_SUBSPLITS
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("ieeerunet.h6", monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                             save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=100, verbose=1, mode='auto')
hist=unet_model.fit(X_new, Y, batch_size=32, epochs=20, validation_data=(T_new, Y1))
```